# Why is the PHP globals variable not working as a argument in a function?

Tags: php, function, arguments, global

Wondered why the use of a GLOBALS variable is causing an error.

```
function makeNewPage($cpage =  $GLOBALS['url']){

    //some code here
}
```

Comment: Don't you have that available in the function?

Answer (score 0):

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

(Presumably, because they are determined at compile time and not run time).

Also

> A function may define C++-style default values for [scalar arguments](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238033/what-does-it-mean-when-data-is-scalar)